# VBA to import selected columns from csv file to excel as text format

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, filesystemobject

I have following VBA code to import selected columns from a csv file to excel. The selected columns should be imported as text. 
For Ex: 000001 should be imported as it is.it should not truncate the leading 0's. I wrote a VBA using file System object to select entire file. But, it is selecting only first 2.

My requirement:
1. Selecting only certain columns
2. All should be imported as text

### My Code:

```
Sub Read_Text_File()
Dim fsoObj As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim fsoTS As Scripting.TextStream
Dim vaData As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set fsoObj = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fsoFile = fsoObj.GetFile("C:\Users\Sandeep\Downloads\TestFile.csv")
Set fsoTS = fsoFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateFalse)


j = 1
Do Until fsoTS.AtEndOfStream
vaData = Split(fsoTS.ReadLine, Chr(44))
Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 2)).Value = vaData
j = j + 1
Loop

fsoTS.Close
Set fsoFile = Nothing
Set fsoObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently mobile, so I cannot provide any example code, but you can automate excel to open the .csv file, format all cells as text and use excel's own ability to split the lines into columns. Finally, you can delete unwanted columns or process only the columns that you want. I suggest that you carry out the above steps manually, recording a macro. Then you can edit the generated code as you desire. If you need more information, please tell me so I can post some code once I have access to vba de.